# How do you descibe a metal that it the opposite of shining?

Tags: word-choice

How do you describe a metal that was once shining, but is so old that it is now mat?

"Matted metal" does not sound right, does it?

Comment: Opaque, probably! ...

Comment: The most suitable description is probably 'Dull'!

Comment: Tarnished, perhaps?

Comment: Do you mean that its finish is now [matte](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/matte)? I'd call it dull or matte, versus glossy or lustrous. But what has your own research shown?

Comment: I was going for matted, but that seems wrong.

Comment: Matte, dull, corroded, rusted, tarnished.  Depends on what you want to describe.

Comment: @user159691: Opaque is the opposite of transparant/translucent. Being shiny is unrelated to opacity. Opaque things can be shiny (e.g. gold, silver), but so can translucent/transparent things (diamonds, glass)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the dullness of age is desirable, the finish may be referred to as a **patina**. (The result of oxidation on various kinds of metal.)

If a metal product is purposely manufactured with a "dull" (as opposed to "shiny") finish, it is called a **satin** finish.

Comment: Your answer uses the word "dull" twice without suggesting it as an answer... To me "dull" is the word the OP is looking for.

Comment: @IanF1 - You're absolutely right. "The metal was dull with age," is succinct and appropriate. My answer is colored by 40+ years in "retail-land" - euphemistic phrases such as: "pre-owned", "vintage", "distressed", and the like, are just what pop into my head first. Mea culpa.